# 'show' returns what I want alongside a weird String

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I have a function that needs to get all of the Integers in a list and display them as a string, I.E "Beans 1.29" should return 129. My function is as follows

```
multDigitsRecTest :: String -> String
multDigitsRecTest [] = ""
multDigitsRecTest (x:xs)
  | isDigit x = show (digitToInt (x), multDigitsRecTest xs)
  | otherwise = multDigitsRecTest xs
```

It seems to return the integer with other weird stuff. Is there a way I can just return the int as the string?

Comment: `show` here will print the *tuple*, so `(5,"somestring")` for example. That string can contain a tuple as well here.

Comment: Yes: Don't use `show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically here want to filter the characters that are digits. So you can implement this as:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit)

multDigitsRecTest :: String -> String
multDigitsRecTest = filter isDigit
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Char> multDigitsRecTest "Beans 1.29"
"129"
```

The reason it is printing noise, is because you call `show (digitToInt x, multDigitsRecTest xs)`. This is a 2-tuple `(Int, String)`. Since both `Int` and `String` are members of the `Show` typeclass. The tuple is as well. It will thus print `(2, "(5, \"\")")` for example.

Comment: Thanks buddy, saved me a lot of bloody hassle!